# split date rang using intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables one is used for all employees' career and the second one is for all interruptions during the work time

this is the structure of my table  employees' career:

```
startDate    endDate    year    codeMission  employeNumber  type
 ---------- ---------------------------------------------------
 2001-01-01 2001-12-31   2001     Tx100       N120        work
 2002-01-01 2002-12-31   2002     Tx100       N120        work
```

then here is the structure of my table interruption

```
startDate     endDate    year   codeMission   employeNumber    type
 ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------
 2001-07-01 2002-04-10   2001     Tx100       N120         interpption
```

Now i would like to create a new table , that contains all employees' career without the interruptions period here is my example

I would like the final table like this :

```
startDate  endDate    year codeMission employeNumber     type
 ---------- --------------------------------------------
 2001-01-01 2001-06-31 2001     Tx100       N120         work
 2001-07-01 2002-04-10 2001     Tx100       N120         interpption
 2002-04-11 2002-12-31 2002     Tx100       N120         work
```

Or

```
startDate  endDate    year codeMission employeNumber     type
 ---------- --------------------------------------------
 2001-01-01 2001-06-31 2001     Tx100       N120         work
 2001-07-01 2001-12-31 2001     Tx100       N120         interpption
 2002-01-01 2002-04-10 2002     Tx100       N120         interpption
 2002-04-11 2002-12-31 2002     Tx100       N120         work
```

Comment: Is the start and end date always going to be 01-01 and 12-31?

Comment: no, it's not all employees' career start like this :(

Comment: Ok, can we at least assume that the employee career starts at startDate from first row and ends at endDate from last row?

Comment: the used order is codeMission, then year, so i guess no

Answer (score 0):

The procedure I followed here is while inserting the data into the new table update the start and end date if it is having an entry in interruption table a

```
 INSERT INTO NewTable
 SELECT NVL(i2.endDate+1,e.startDate) AS startDate
        ,NVL(i1.startDate-1,e.endDate) AS endDate    
        ,e.year
        ,e.codeMission
        ,e.employeNumber
        ,e.type
 FROM Employee e
 LEFT JOIN Interruption i1 ON e.employeNumber=i1.employeNumber AND YEAR(e.startDate)=YEAR(i1.startDate)
 LEFT JOIN Interruption i2 ON e.employeNumber=i1.employeNumber AND YEAR(e.endDate)=YEAR(i2.endDate)
```

Now we have transformed the data in employee table to match with interruption table so now we move the data in interruption table

```
 INSERT INTO NewTable
 SELECT startDate
        ,endDate    
        ,year
        ,codeMission
        ,employeNumber
        ,type
 FROM Interruption
```